# Flurry v 4.2.3 linking issues

Tags: ios, flurry

I'm trying to update to the latest version of Flurry, from 4.2.2 to 4.2.3. I've updated the files, but now I'm getting all sorts of linking errors.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setData:forKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper dataForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper removeObjectForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_SecItemUpdate", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper updateValueData:forKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setData:forKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setData:forKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setupSearchForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrGeneric", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setupSearchForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setupSearchForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setupSearchForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setupSearchForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper dataForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper dataForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper dataForKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setData:forKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
      -[FlurryKeychainWrapper updateValueData:forKey:] in libSDLibrary.a(libFlurry.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It's rather frustrating to say the least. I've included the SystemConfiguration framework (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347882/missing-required-architecture-armv7-in-file)). I'm running xCode 4.6.3. Any ideas on where else the problem could lie?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to add `Security.framework` because the symbols mentioned in the linker error are from that framework.

---

From [Flurry update page](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/FAQ/4.2.3_update#How_do_I_update_my_SDK.3F)

**How do I update?**

> Download the latest version of Flurry’s SDK (version 4.2.3) here.
>   Include Apple’s Security Framework in your build process. (see the FAQ entry below for details on how to do this)

**Is the "Security" framework mandatory?**

> To ensure the integrity of your data, Flurry requires that you include this framework in your updated app.

Comment: @SD_Guru Did this help? If yes, you can mark as accepted answer so that your question gets removed from the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: I've added the Security framework as well, to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: @SD_Guru Adding the `Security.framework` should resolve these errors for sure. Are you creating any library/framework which uses this flurry library or just adding the flurry lib to an app? I see the errors mention `libSDLibrary.a`.

Comment: @SD_Guru Make sure that the application which uses your `libSDLibrary.a` should also link to all the frameworks your library is linking including `Security.framework`.

Comment: That did it, Amar! Yes, it was a nested library problem with the final application not linking to the security framework. Thanks so much!

Comment: yes... right... worked for me after adding security frame work  +1  @Amar

Comment: You saved my day. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Does this mean we now need to mention our apps 'contain encryption' when uploading them to apple?